# Custom Rectangle having circles on Corners windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, canvas, crop, rectangles

I am developing a photo app in windows phone 7. I want a Rectangle having circles on corner of it, that will allow the user to resize the rectangle from the corner (circles) and if the user want to Move the rectangle then Drag it in any direction. See the Sample 1 & 2.

I am using this mechanism to Crop the image via this rectangle, You mostly will have seen this type of control in the Image editor especially in iPhone photo apps. I have checked all sample aaps and other ideas on google.com but never seen such type of idea. I also read the Canvas and their manipulation event concept but don't know how to implement and even don't understand that is it used for such mechanism or not? Please a complete source code in this regard may highly be appreciated.

See the Sample figures, you will get the idea, what exactly I want.

[image: Crop Image Rectangle having corner circles]

Comment: Why this question is tagged `powershell`? I've Edited to remove it and added `windows-phone-7` tag...

Comment: I have changed the tag, it was mistakenly tagged probably! Now plz answer me to the point, I have explained my question by images too, to understand in better way. Please!

Comment: I've fixed your tags...

Comment: Plz answer my question

Comment: U please give a general idea, how this be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `UserControl` that will represent such shape. Put a single `Grid` inside the `UserControl` and place a single `Rectangle` and four `Circles` in it. For example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Rectangle Stroke="Green"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               Margin="25" />

    <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Stroke="Red"
             Width="50" Height="50"/>
    <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
             Stroke="Red"
             Width="50" Height="50"/>
    <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Stroke="Red"
             Width="50" Height="50"/>
    <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
             Stroke="Red"
             Width="50" Height="50"/>
</Grid>
```

Style it as you please and add the necessary events for handling touch and drag events.

Comment: Thanks Toni Petrina for ur response. I already have made this custom control, but actually don't understand, how to implement such mechanism, that when I drag the rectangle it moves and when I want to resize the rectangle it should be resized by Hold&Drag from the corner circles. Please give me the full hard code, I know u have understand my problem, so u can solve it. Please!

Comment: It is not trivial to write nor I have enough time. You need to use Manipulation* events to handle movement. Process those events and move your control on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

XAML

```
<Grid>

        <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

            <Image Source="Assets/someImage.png" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0.3" ></Image>
            <Image Name="imgSauce" Source="Assets/someImage.png" >
                <Image.Clip>
                    <RectangleGeometry x:Name="clipRect" ></RectangleGeometry>
                </Image.Clip>
            </Image>
            <Rectangle Name="rectTopLeft" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="-10" Fill="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform></TranslateTransform>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Name="rectTopRight" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="-10" Fill="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform></TranslateTransform>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Name="rectBotLeft" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="-10" Fill="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform></TranslateTransform>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Name="rectBotRight" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="-10" Fill="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform></TranslateTransform>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

C# Code

```
public partial class CropPage : Page
{

    private Rectangle _draggedRect = null;


    public CropPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        var rects = new Rectangle[] { rectTopRight, rectTopLeft, rectBotRight, rectBotLeft };
        Point _dragOrigin =new Point();
        double origLeftPerc= 0, origRightPerc = 0, origTopPerc = 0, origBotPerc = 0;

        var setOrigin = new Action<Point>((p) => {
            _dragOrigin = p;
                origLeftPerc = this._clipLeftPerc;
                origRightPerc = this._clipRightPerc;
                origTopPerc = this._clipTopPerc;
                origBotPerc = this._clipBotPerc;
        });

        foreach (var aRect in rects)
        {
            aRect.MouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) => {
                var r = (Rectangle)s;
                _draggedRect = r;
                setOrigin( e.GetPosition(this.imgSauce));

                r.CaptureMouse();
            };

            aRect.MouseLeftButtonUp += (s, e) => {                    
                _draggedRect = null;
            };

            aRect.MouseMove += (s, e) => {
                if (_draggedRect != null) {

                    var pos = e.GetPosition(this.imgSauce);

                    if (s == this.rectTopLeft || s == this.rectTopRight) {
                        // Adjust top
                        _clipTopPerc = origTopPerc + (pos.Y - _dragOrigin.Y) / imgSauce.ActualHeight;
                    }
                    if (s == this.rectTopLeft || s == this.rectBotLeft) {
                        // Adjust Left
                        _clipLeftPerc = origLeftPerc + (pos.X - _dragOrigin.X) / imgSauce.ActualWidth;
                    }
                    if (s == this.rectBotLeft || s == this.rectBotRight) {
                        // Adjust bottom
                        _clipBotPerc = origBotPerc - (pos.Y - _dragOrigin.Y) / imgSauce.ActualHeight;
                    }
                    if (s == this.rectTopRight || s == this.rectBotRight) {
                        // Adjust Right
                        _clipRightPerc = origRightPerc - (pos.X - _dragOrigin.X) / imgSauce.ActualWidth;
                    }

                    this.updateClipAndTransforms();
                }
            };
        }

        var draggingImg = false;

        imgSauce.MouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) => {
           setOrigin( e.GetPosition(this.imgSauce));
            imgSauce.CaptureMouse();
            draggingImg = true;
        };

        imgSauce.MouseLeftButtonUp += (s, e) => {
            draggingImg = false;
        };

        imgSauce.MouseMove += (s, e) => {
            if (draggingImg) {
                var pos = e.GetPosition(this.imgSauce);

                var xAdjust = (pos.X - _dragOrigin.X) / imgSauce.ActualWidth;
                var yAdjust = (pos.Y - _dragOrigin.Y) / imgSauce.ActualHeight;

                _clipLeftPerc = origLeftPerc + xAdjust;
                _clipRightPerc = origRightPerc - xAdjust;
                _clipTopPerc = origTopPerc + yAdjust;
                _clipBotPerc = origBotPerc - yAdjust;

                this.updateClipAndTransforms();
            }
        };

        imgSauce.SizeChanged += (x,y) => {
            this.updateClipAndTransforms();
        };

        this.updateClipAndTransforms();
    }



    private double _clipLeftPerc, _clipRightPerc, _clipTopPerc, _clipBotPerc =  0;

    void updateClipAndTransforms()
    {
        // Check bounds
        if (_clipLeftPerc + _clipRightPerc >= 1)
            _clipLeftPerc = (1 - _clipRightPerc) - 0.04;
        if (_clipTopPerc + _clipBotPerc >= 1)
            _clipTopPerc = (1 - _clipBotPerc) - 0.04;

        if (_clipLeftPerc < 0)
            _clipLeftPerc = 0;
        if (_clipRightPerc < 0)
        _clipRightPerc = 0;
        if (_clipBotPerc < 0)
            _clipBotPerc = 0;
        if (_clipTopPerc < 0)
            _clipTopPerc = 0;
        if (_clipLeftPerc >= 1)
            _clipLeftPerc = 0.99;
        if (_clipRightPerc >= 1)
            _clipRightPerc = 0.99;
        if (_clipBotPerc >= 1)
            _clipBotPerc = 0.99;
        if (_clipTopPerc >= 1)
            _clipTopPerc = 0.99;


        // Image Clip
        var leftX = _clipLeftPerc * this.imgSauce.ActualWidth;
        var topY = _clipTopPerc * this.imgSauce.ActualHeight;

        clipRect.Rect = new Rect(leftX, topY, (1 -_clipRightPerc) * this.imgSauce.ActualWidth - leftX, (1 - _clipBotPerc) *  this.imgSauce.ActualHeight - topY);

        // Rectangle Transforms
        ((TranslateTransform)this.rectTopLeft.RenderTransform).X = clipRect.Rect.X;
        ((TranslateTransform)this.rectTopLeft.RenderTransform).Y = clipRect.Rect.Y;
        ((TranslateTransform)this.rectTopRight.RenderTransform).X = -_clipRightPerc * this.imgSauce.ActualWidth;
        ((TranslateTransform)this.rectTopRight.RenderTransform).Y = clipRect.Rect.Y;
        ((TranslateTransform)this.rectBotLeft.RenderTransform).X = clipRect.Rect.X;
        ((TranslateTransform)this.rectBotLeft.RenderTransform).Y = - _clipBotPerc *  this.imgSauce.ActualHeight;
        ((TranslateTransform)this.rectBotRight.RenderTransform).X = -_clipRightPerc * this.imgSauce.ActualWidth;
        ((TranslateTransform)this.rectBotRight.RenderTransform).Y = -_clipBotPerc * this.imgSauce.ActualHeight;
    }

}
```